# Concatenating chars with String.charAt() and + operator turns them into encoded UTF-8

Tags: java, hibernate, utf-8, char, concatenation

I'm having trouble properly concatenating characters out of a `String[]` using `String.charAt()` and `+` operator with the following method.

```
private PcbGroup createPcbGroup(String[] metadata, PcbGroup pcbGroup) {
    char group_short = metadata[2].charAt(0);
    
    pcbGroup.setId(Integer.parseInt(metadata[0]));
    pcbGroup.setGroup_name(metadata[1]);
    for (int i = 1; i < metadata[2].length(); i++) {
        group_short += metadata[2].charAt(i);
    }
    pcbGroup.setGroup_short(group_short);

    // create and return pcbGroup of this metadata
    return pcbGroup;
}
```

I'm reading a CSV file with `BufferedReader` and populate `String[] metadata` with it. The content of the `String[] metadata` is `[3, "Foo", ML]`. The line `char group_short = metadata[2].charAt(0);` correctly assings `'M'` to `char group_short`. It then turns into `?`  (space intended) when concatenating it with the second character `'L'`.

When I save this object, Hibernate complains about noncorrect String value which appears to be `'\xC2\x99'`.

```
Hibernate: insert into pcb_group (group_name, group_short, id) values (?, ?, ?)

2022-11-22 10:41:35.902  WARN 2988 --- [           main] 
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1366, SQLState: HY000

2022-11-22 10:41:35.903 ERROR 2988 --- [           main] 
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : (conn=3030) Incorrect string value: '\xC2\x99' for 
column 'group_short' at row 1

2022-11-22 10:41:35.903  INFO 2988 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     
: HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
```

I'm struggling with this little thing for a few hours now and it's getting on my nerves, could use some help.

Comment: You understand that `group_short += metadata[2].charAt(i);` is *changing* the character `group_short` holds, not concatenating characters?

Comment: `char` is a primitive, actually a number, so `+=` is adding the values - the `+` operator only works as string concatenation if at least one of the operands is a `String` - it is hard to understand what the goal of that is, why not use `metadata[2]`  directly? Concatenating all its chars into a String, is just creating a second string with the same content (on the other hand. a `char` cannot {*correctly*) hold two letters - assuming that `setGroup_short()` only accepts a `char`)

Comment: Why are you even building `group_short` like this? It starts with the first character of `metadata[2]`, and then you add each other character to it. In the end, `group_short` will be identical to `metadata[2]`. Since `pcbGroup.setGroup_short` obviously takes a singe `char`, it's most likely that you only need to set the first character only. You cannot store more than 1 character in a single `char`.

Comment: @RobSpoor I did not see the forest for the trees in this case. I was way too fixated on a wrongly implemented entity class where my predecessors used char instead of String for `group_short`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line doesn't do what you seem to think it does:

```
group_short += metadata[2].charAt(i);
```

While this might look like a string concatenation to you, it's not. `group_short` is of type `char` meaning it holds **a single character**<sup>*</sup>.

What this does is add the codepoint value of the other characters to the one of the first character which doesn't result in anything semantically meaningful for your use case (one *could* argue that it's a very simple kind of hashing, but it's not even good at that).

What you want to do is have a `String` (or ideally `StringBuilder`) variable and do proper concatenation:

```
String group_short = "" + metadata[2].charAt(0);

// and later in the loop:
group_short += metadata[2].charAt(i);
```

Note that with this code `group_short` will be *exactly* the same value as `metadata[2]` at the end of the loop, making all of that code equivalent to (but way less efficient than) `group_short = Objects.nonNull(metadata[2])`.

<sup>* Due to the complexity of Unicode and Java Strings using UTF-16 this is not *entirely* accurate as multiple `char` values can be required to make up a single "character" in the "human language" sense, it's close enough for this issue.</sup>

Comment: I'd prefer a `StringBuilder`, especially as the additions are done in a loop.

Comment: @user16320675: you're right about 1 (even *including* the UTF-16/codepoint issue). I'll edit my answer to reflect that. Regarding 2.: can you give a source on that? I don't know of anything having fundamentally changed about the cost of repeated string concatenation inside a loop.

Comment: @user16320675 I've checked with `javap` that Java 11 and 17 indeed use the `StringConcatFactory`. That's very likely indeed much better than `StringBuilder` for simple string concatenation. However, it will still produce a lot of intermediate `String` objects when used in a loop. With an explicit `StringBuilder`, the number of intermediate objects will become a lot smaller (limited to the `StringBuilder` and its internal storage reallocations).

Comment: @user16320675 regarding note 1: I think that OP though that the method that takes only a single `char` could be called with some kind of compound character. Because you're right - `String group_short = metadata[2]` will be the best way to build it.

Comment: @Rob - last year I wrote a JMH test for that - the difference in time is very small, but the `+`  concatenation wins for *larger* loops; I have not tested memory usage, sure the `+` will need more intermediate instances, but the `StringBuilder` will also eventually have to increase its `char[]` and all this intermediate instances will shortly be available for GC

Comment: @user16320675: that seems like something that the compiler uses internally to turn string concatenation into a more optimal action in a way that `StringBuilder` was used previously. I'm not sure that this fundamentally changes the advice of `don't do `string += otherString` inside of a loop. I'd be interested in checking your JMH test, but frankly I'll need a bit more convincing than the equivalent of Fermats Last Theorem ("I have discovered a truly marvelous proof of this, which this margin is too narrow to contain.") to get rid of my dislike of string concatenation in loops.